# Installing touchpad drivers

Tags: drivers, windows-10, mouse, touchpad

I want to install a different driver for my touchpad (synaptics driver) so that I would be able to use three fingers tap to middle click.

I have no idea what kind of driver I have (my computer is an XPS13 9350 from Dell, under windows 10) and it seems that no touchpad drivers are available on Dell.fr for my computer.

My touchpad is a PS/2 compatible mouse and I saw that synaptics drivers were available for this touchpad and installed them but it looks like nothing changed, as if nothing was installed because there is no sign of synaptics in my programs, nor in the notification area.

Is there something wrong with my installation ?
I executed the setup.exe file and restarted my computer.